# RegionMeasure on packed array crashes Kernel in version 11.1

Tags: bugs, regions, kernel, crash, packed-arrays

**Bug introduced in 11.1.0 and fixed in 11.1.1**

---

In version 11.1.0, applying `RegionMeasure` or `Area` to a region with packed coordinates crashes the Kernel:

```
coords = Developer`ToPackedArray@{{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}};
Area[Rectangle @@ coords]
```

In versions 11.0.1 and 10.4.1 there is no crash.

One workaround is to unpack the packed arrays manually, but it is tedious:

```
coords = Developer`FromPackedArray@coords;
Area[Rectangle @@ coords]
```

> ```
> 1.
> ```

Is there a better way (setting a system-wide option, fixing code of internal function, etc.)?

Comment: What is your question? It  would seem best to report this behavior to Wolfram Support.

Comment: No crash in 11.0 either.

Comment: @MarcoB Added a question. If you are in a position to report, please do it.

Comment: It looks like `RegionQ` is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been fixed as of version [11.1.1](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html).

```
coords = Developer`ToPackedArray@{{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}};
Through[{RegionQ, Area}[Rectangle @@ coords]]

(* {True, 1.} *)
```

Comment: Where did you download the 11.1.1? I only have 11.1.0 in my user portal.

Comment: It's being rolled out today.

Comment: Will my Mathematica update automatically or I need to download the whole installer from user portal?

Comment: You would need the installer (as usual).